# Compare two strings and check the changed value in a contain range

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, switch-statement

I have 6 properties:

```
oldprop1,oldprop2,oldprop3
newprop1,newprop2,newprop3
```

I am going to check if the value changed. If it changed in a certain combination of ways, then I want to log it.

If these 5 changes happen, then it should be logged:

```
P to Y
P to N
blank to Y -- here blank means ""
blank to N
N to Y
```

What I am doing now

```
if (!oldprop1.Trim().Equals(newprop1.Trim()) && (oldprop1.ContainsAny("P", "N","")) && newprop1.ContainsAny("Y", "N"))
{
    //log me to DB
}
if (!oldprop2.Trim().Equals(newprop2.Trim()) && (oldprop2.ContainsAny("P", "N", "")) && newprop2.ContainsAny("Y", "N"))
{
    //log me to DB
}
if (!oldprop3.Trim().Equals(newprop3.Trim()) && (oldprop3.ContainsAny("P", "N", "")) && newprop3.ContainsAny("Y", "N"))
{
    //log me to DB
}

public static bool ContainsAny(this string haystack, params string[] needles)
{
    foreach (string needle in needles)
    {
        if (haystack.Contains(needle))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Is there any better way to write this?

Comment: A string cannot contain an empty string, a string either is, or is not, empty.

Answer (score 1):

better to use **switch** statement .here is the code

```
 public void CompareAndLog(string first, string second)
    {
        switch (first)
        {

            case "P": if (second == "Y" || second == "N") ;//log me to db
                break;
            case "N": if (second == "Y") ; //log me to db
                break;
            case "": if (second == "Y" || second == "N") ;//log me to db 
                break;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method where you pass in `oldpropX` and `newpropX` and do the logic in there, then you just do:

```
if (SomeFunc(oldprop1, newprop1) || SomeFunc(oldprop2, newprop2)...)
{
// log to DB.
}
```

`SomeFunc()` would do the `Equals` check and the P,N,etc. check.